# Cannot store input number in SQL with decimal format

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent

Adding a new record always ends with a `null` value. Other columns work, except this one.

```sql
`paid` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
```

```php
'paid' => $request->input('paidammount')
```

```html
<input type="number" name="paidammount" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01">
```

How can I fix this issue and store the value from this exact input?

Comment: Show the full `form` html tag. How are you sending it? What method (`POST`, `GET`, etc) are you using? If you `dd($request)`, do you see the value anywhere else? Also check the browser console network's tab and see if you are correctly sending the data with that name and the expected data, so we make sure the browser is (at least) sending the right data...

Comment: Form is quite long, so there is no chance to publish it here. Function "dd" returns a proper value. Other inputs from the same form work and data is stored properly. Only this one input cannot pass value to SQL.

Comment: I have not updated model in Laravel ... Problem is solved

Comment: What was the issue? This question is of no help to anyone coming to it in the future...

Comment: `$request->input('paidammount')` is maybe returning a string. Try casting it to float first `'paid' => (float) $request->input('paidammount')`